# I have the music logo stuck when I click music,

Tags: iphone, music

I have turned it on and off, hit the music app and it's still frozen.

What other options do I have to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this on iOS or OS X? Make sure you specify, even if you're answering your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I perform a restore with iTunes from a previous backup and I was able to get past the screen.
After the restore I hit the music App and now I am able to use it .